# How to enable POJO mapping for Java 8 Instant class?

Tags: java, jackson, date, jersey-1.0

I have a `StartupListener` which registers the `JavaTime` module. But I am still getting the error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.Instant` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

```
@WebListener
public class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        logger.log(Level.CONFIG, "servlet content initialized");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    }
}
```

I am using Jersy with `POJOMapping` enabled. My model class has `Instant dateCreated;` which fails. My dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

How to fix this?

---

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ProductDTO {
    private String name;
    private String description;

    private String mrp;
    private String price;
    private String savePrice;

    private String url;
    private String imageURL;
    private String ratings;
    private String ratingsCount;

    private Instant dateCreated;

    public Instant getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Instant dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

   // ..
```

---

I have added the `lombok` dependency and annotated as mentioned in the answer, but I am still getting the same error. Please find the error log:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: Nov 14, 2019 12:29:42 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
[INFO] GCLOUD: SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
[INFO] GCLOUD: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.Instant` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 1245] (through reference chain: com.proto.model.ProductDTO["dateModified"])
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1589)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1055)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1682)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:977)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:814)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
```

---

I am populating the ProductDTO with custom values and sending it as a POST to a rest endpoint which is an app engine task worker.

```
ProductDTO {
name = "8X (Black, 4GB RAM, 64GB Storage)"
description = ""
mrp = "7,999.00"
price = ""
url = ""
imageURL = ""
ratings = "4.4"
ratingsCount = "5,910"
dateCreated = {Date@7067} "Thu Nov 14 12:41:14 IST 2019"
dateModified = {Instant@9346} "2019-11-14T07:12:47.255Z"
}
```

The endpoint that accepts this dto is

```
@POST
@Path("/transform")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public WorkerResponse transform(ProductDTO dto) throws IOException {
    // ...
}
```

and this fails the mapping.

Comment: show please your model class

Comment: It's a normal POJO class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Comment: i bet you dont have `getters/setters` for your fields

Comment: I have updated the question with the model.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure your `Json` node has proper name - `dateCreated`.
Then make sure you have default `@NoArgsConstructor/@AllArgsConstructor` counstructors.
Try to modify your `ObjectMapper` with the following:

`ObjectMapper mapper  = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules().disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);`

Jackson deserealizes `Instant` as a timestamp by default, so you need to disable it.

usage of lombok annotations :

```
  @AllArgsConstructor
     @NoArgsConstructor
     @Data
     @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ProductDTO {
...
}
```

Comment: This is not working, I am getting the same error. I am not sure where to put the `NoArgsConstructor` annotation. I am not using Lombok.

Comment: @jsloop this is class level annotation. you should put it on your class pojo. Like: `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductDTO { ... }`

Comment: What dependency should I include to get this annotation? I am getting `Cannot resolve symbol NoArgConstructor`.

Comment: @jsloop `import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;` i edited my answer as well

Comment: I have added the deps, but getting the same exception. I doubt the Jackson is not picking up the object mapper registration.

Comment: let me take a look at your JSON, i will try to deserialize it in accordance with your needs

Comment: `Instant` type belongs to `dateModified` field, `dateCreated` is a `Date` type.

Comment: Yes, since I could not get the instant field to work I am using Date temporarily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202312/discussion-between-vault23-and-jsloop).